# Intercept and block network traffic on iOS

Tags: ios, proxy

## Background

My client's iOS application makes use of a third party library for advertising. About once a week we'll find that enormous numbers of our users are experiencing a crash because of some specific advert the API is presenting. When this happens our current reaction is to turn off all adverts until it is resolved.

We'd like to have some kind of per advert control.

## Doing it properly

Ideally the third party library would provide an ID for the advert it's about to display and give the App an opportunity to block that particular advert. We'd log this ID and if it correlates with crashes (which is usually very obvious), block it.

However, getting the ID tracking in will require negotiation between my client's departments, and the the advert provider's departments, which will take some time, if it happens at all.

## The work around

As an alternative, I'm wondering if there is a way that our app could intercept (and then potentially block) the network traffic of the third party library? Essentially run a transparent proxy that vets network traffic for our whole process (within which the library is running).

- Are there hooks in iOS that would support this?
- Just knowing the url requests would be a good start, this could at least be logged to help us isolate the advert and request it's not sent any more.
- I'm not after a complete solution: pointers to useful areas in the API would be fantastic.
- Any example code of something similar?
- Other ideas for other ways to achieve the same result?

Comment: Terrible answer for this, but it will more than likely work, even though this is a bandaid to a larger problem you are having, if this is a critical issue, then I would just "@try" "@catch" this sucker and see if this solves it until the 3rd dev gets their sh*t together.

Comment: No, that's a good suggestion. I've taken a look, and it's not in one of our threads, so I don't think that's going to work?

Comment: yeah, the only other option I can think if is cookie mutation, but then you are getting into territory that is horribly difficult to control. The cookie mutation I've used before when you look through cookies and inject invalid information into them so they can't connect to the web site in question, but this isn't a long term solution.

Comment: Ever find a network-based solution to this? We are in a similar situation where a 3rd party SDK is creating multiple sockets connections that we would like to either intercept or block altogether.

Comment: @Shoerob I never did, sorry.